# In Next js API route TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')

Tags: next.js, vercel

I am trying to create an API route with Next.js 13 `app` directory as below, but when I am throwing an error, like:

```
throw createHttpError(FORBIDDEN, "You are already registered")
```

I am getting an error like the one below:

> error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')

```js
export async function POST(request) {
  await dbConnect();
  let reqBody = await request.json();
  let result;
  let workProgress = 0;
  const { email, fullName, password } = reqBody;
  try {
    const foundUser = await findUser({ email: email });
    if (!foundUser) {
      //Hash password
      const hashedPassword = await hashPassword(password);
      workProgress++;
      //Create User
      result = await insertUser({
        email,
        fullName,
        password: hashedPassword,
      });
      workProgress++;
      //Create token
      const token = await createToken({
        userId: result._id,
        token: crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex"),
        purpose: "verify_email",
      });
      const url = `http://localhost:3000/auth/emailVerify?id=${result._id}&token=${token.token}`;
      //Send verification email
      await sendEmail(result.email, "Verify Your Email Address", url, "verify_email", undefined);

      return NextResponse.json(
        {
          message: `Successfully registered,an email sent to ${result.email} please verify the email`,
        },
        { status: 201 }
      );
    } else {
      const foundToken = await findToken({
        userId: foundUser._id,
        purpose: "verify_email",
      });
      if (foundUser && foundUser?.verified) {
        throw createHttpError(FORBIDDEN, "You are already registered");
      } else if (foundUser && !foundUser?.verified && foundToken) {
        throw createHttpError(FORBIDDEN, "Regstration process pending ,please verify your email");
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (workProgress >= 2 && result) {
      await deleteUser({ _id: result._id });
    }
    handleErrors(error);
  }
}
```

Here is the handle error function:

```js
export const handleErrors =  (err) => {
  if (createHttpError.isHttpError(err) && err.expose) {
    // Handle all errors thrown by http-errors module
      return NextResponse.json(
        {
          error: err.name,
          message: err.message,
        },
        { status: err.statusCode }
      );
  } else if (err instanceof mongoose.Error.CastError) {
    //Handle cast error

     return NextResponse.json(
       {
         error: "Invalid data",
         message: "Invalid data provided for the request",
       },
       { status: 400 }
     );
  } 
  // else if (err instanceof ValidationError) {
  //   // Handle yup validation errors
  //   return res.status(400).end(err.errors.join(","));
  // } 
  else if (err instanceof mongoose.Error.ValidationError) {
    //Handle mongoose validation error
  return NextResponse.json(
    {
      error: err.name,
      message: err.message,
    },
    { status: 400 }
  );
    
  } else if (err.name === "MongoServerError" && err.code === 11000) {
    //handle mongoDB error
     return NextResponse.json(
       {
         error: err.name,
         message: "Duplicate record found",
       },
       { status: 400 }
     );
   
  } else if (err.name === "MongoServerError") {
    //handle mongoDB error
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        error: err.name,
        message: err.message,
      },
      { status: err.code }
    );
  } else {
    // default to 500 server error
    console.log(err);

    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        message: "Internal Server Error....",
      },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you add the code for `deleteUser` and `handleErrors`? Are you using `headers` in any of these 2 functions?

Comment: I think I got the answer why I am facing the problem. forgot to return  handleErrors()

Answer (score 0):

An [API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route) with the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router should return a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) or an extended version of it with the help of [`NextResponse`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route#nextresponse).

When you throw an error, you are not returning the result of `handleErrors`, hence Next.js is getting an `undefined`.

This should fixe your issue:

```js
export async function POST(request) {
  // ..
  try {
    // ...
  } catch (error) {
    // ...
    return handleErrors(error);
  }
}
```